# Ubuntu 13.04 can't read Arabic texts

Tags: 13.04, language-support, encoding, arabic

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 , it can't read Arabic letters and words properly. that what I get when I open files contains Arabic, please notice that same files are showed correctly on windows:

```
ÇáÞÇäæä íÌÈÑ ÇáíåæÏ Úáì ÇáÚíÔ
ÈãäØÞÉ ãÚÒæáÉ ãä ÇáãÏíäÉ ÊÏÚì ÇáÌíÊæ
```

Comment: ...and what are the files you open?

Comment: Seems the matter of **encoding**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ubuntu in Arabic?
If not then I would suggest downloading the language packs straight from System Settings--->Language Support--->Install/Remove Language

Active Internet connection required BTW

Comment: What makes you think you need to have all of Ubuntu in Arabic only to read an Arabic text? Suppose, the OP is a student of Arabic, and only wants to open an exercise? Changing the interface language just for that is a major overkill, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libfribidi0 libfribidi-dev
```

Also, install [THIS](https://launchpad.net/~behnam/+archive/ppa/+build/574785/+files/bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0~ppa4_i386.deb) package.