# arabic language are displayed as question mark

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, 16.04

I have ububntu 12.04 installed. and despite i installed the arabic language from langauge support, when I open an application all the arabic language in its interface are displayed as queston mark. how to solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/648823/how-to-read-ansi-encoded-files-in-the-right-way

Comment: @FrankSchrijver the link you provided does not offer a solution as the post is mainly about how to read a file in different encodings, while my case is, the interface of a software is in unreadable text

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/350213/ubuntu-13-04-cant-read-arabic-texts this one suggests "suggest downloading the language packs straight from System Settings--->Language Support--->Install/Remove Language"

Comment: @FrankSchrijver in my question i ststed that i installed the required langauge pack for arabic

Comment: yes im sorry. have you tried changing your locale? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Comment: @FrankSchrijver actually i dont know who to do it..would please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Not all locale's are available so we must generate them:

```
sudo locale-gen ar_SA.UTF-8
```

Change the locale

```
update-locale LANG=ar_SA.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

then reboot